# Добавить атрибут в ответ ActiveRecord Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть таблица состоящая из колонок `firstname` `lastname`.
как при запросе `Users::find()->all();` получить в ответе еще одну колонку `fullname`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то достаточно в модель `User` добавить геттер:

```
public function getFullName() {
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

и тогда он также будет доступен при обращении как к свойству, пример:

```
$model->fullName
```

---

Если нужно, чтоб был доступен атрибут после операции `find`, то в *Yii2* есть метод [afterFind](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterFind()-detail), который выполняется после того, как исполнился AR запрос и заполнил данные. Таким образом в модели можно дописать:

```
public function afterFind() {
     $this->fullName = $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;;
}
```

при этом надо не забыть добавить в модель соответствующее поле:

```
public $fullName;
```

Comment: это в случае если я буду обращатся напрямую к объекту так как вы написали. если же я просто распечатаю ответ `Users::find()->all();` этой колонки там не будет

Comment: Тогда в дополнение к гетеру, можно создать публичную переменную и заполнить ее в afterFind

Comment: @Shadow33 на выходе из `Users::find()->all()` у вас массив объектов `Users`. При выводе во вьюв вы работаете именно с объектом, и метод `getFullName()` будет доступен. Или магическое свойство `fullName`, доступное на основе одноименного геттера.

Comment: @KiTE ответ возвращается из котроллера в формате json и уже не имеет эти свойста

Comment: @Shadow33 добавил в ответ..... по идее это тоже самое, о чём писал  Maksym Tymofeiev: используй метод `afterFind`

Comment: @Shadow33 вам сюда http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs-ru/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-fields

Answer (score 1):

Как выяснилось поле должно выводиться через rest-контроллер.

Для этого нужно переопределить метод `User::fields()`, например, самый простой способ:

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields['fullname'] = function () {
        return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
    };
    return $fields;
}
```

Подробнее [в документации](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs-ru/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-fields).